# Is Ramashtakam an independent work of Vyasa or part of a Purana?

Tags: scripture, puranas, rama, vyasa, stotra

[Ramashtakam](http://www.celextel.org/stotras/vishnu/ramashtakam.html) which you can listen [here](https://youtu.be/410Jen0QVfk) on YouTube, is an octet on Lord Rama and is attributed to Vyasa. It also ends with the following:

> Ramashtakam padathi ya sukaram supunyam, 
>   **Vyasena bhashithamidham**, srunuthe manushya, 
>   Vidhyam sriyam vipula soukhyamanantha keerthim, 
>   Samprapya deha vilaye labhathe cha moksham. || 9 ||
>
> He who reads or hears this octet on Rama, which is easy to understand,
>   which gives rise to good deeds, **which is written by Sage Vyasa**, would
>   get knowledge, wealth, pleasure and limitless fame. And once he leaves
>   his body, he would also get salvation.

Is Ramashtakam an independent work of Vyasa or is it taken from a Purana? Where does it appear in Hindu scripture?

Comment: Until now I was only familiar with two poems called Ramashtakam - the one found in the Ananda Ramayana, which you can read [here](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/jun97/0058.html), and the one composed by Ramanujacharya's guru's guru Yamunacharya, which you can see here: http://stotraratna.sathyasaibababrotherhood.org/ra15.htm But this is different from both of those.