# Is there any evidence that the rAmASTakaM was actually written by vyAsa?

Tags: rama, vyasa

The one I am talking about is this: https://stotranidhi.com/en/rama-ashtakam-in-english/

Comment: Probably similar to https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11430/is-ramashtakam-an-independent-work-of-vyasa-or-part-of-a-purana

Comment: @Just_Do_It Unfortunately that didn't get an answer either.